# Calculated Member for the TOTAL of a measure for multiple Dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube-script

I am trying to TOTAL a measure with a calculated measure AS

```
CALCULATE;     
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Total On Hand Amount]
AS ([Warehouses].[Warehouses].[All],[Measures].[On Hand Amount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

This is working when I have warehouse Dimension selected but I want to make it dynamic so that it would work for any other dimensions/hierarchies as well without them being added to the code.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use [Root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/root-mdx)

```
CALCULATE;     
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Total On Hand Amount]
AS AGGREGATE(Root(),[Measures].[On Hand Amount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Here is a small example with:
[image: Total Sales Amount]

[image: ROOT to get the value on the ALL level/default member for all dimensions]

Comment: This code did not work for me. It would just return NULL values for [Total On Hand Amount] for any dimension. Am I missing anything else on this code?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would consider this next time but I got a working code now here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108651/calculated-members-with-multiple-attribute-hierarchy-mdx

Comment: But this does answer your question correctly? You even use Root on your other Duplicated question like I suggested here... Please accept this as an answer so at least it may help others.